# Odd behavior with angular-ui-router between javascript and typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am writing a large `angular 1.5+` application in `Typescript` and have hit a strange snag in the way `$rootScope.$on` is behaving.

Using this code, there is a controller attached to the `sidenav` `component` just fine; it works great; https://embed.plnkr.co/NpjnpZ7Bj6pFG0BoAxRa/

But the same code in typescript seems to keep failing. This is how I scaffold out my component...

```
import { Module } from 'app/common/module';
import 'angular';

class ngComponent {
    constructor() { 
       this.controller = Controller;
       this.templateUrl = '/api/views/common/sidenav.html';
    }
}

class Controller {
   static $inject = ['$rootScope','$state'];
   constructor($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $state: ng.ui.IState) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', (e: ng.IAngularEvent, to: ng.ui.IState, from: ng.ui.IState) => {
      console.log('this code never runs.');
   }
}

Module.component('sidenav', new ngComponent());
```

I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary; Here is `app/common/module`.

```
export var Module: ng.IModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

I can't seem to figure out why the event isn't happening.

Comment: might try upgrading router

Comment: I'm on `1.0.0-beta3`, the newest possible.

Comment: ok...does it work going down to older version then...like is in the plunker?

Comment: brb. while I go punt kittens or something.

Comment: Yes. It works if I go down to `0.3.1`.

Comment: poor kittens!!! ... hope it's not the same litter I kick around

Comment: File a bug report if it doesn't exist yet, and stop using beta versions of libraries :)